# Python Pandas DataFrame Data Identification

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I took data from an `.xlsx` file and stored it in the dataframe. The data frame is called `df`, and the size of the dataframe is (51,3). 51 rows. 3 columns. The columns are unnamed and numbered 0,1,2. The rows are indexed from 0-50. What syntax would I use to extract data from a dataframe with pandas in python and put it into a csv? I know I would use `DataFrame.to_csv("outputFile.csv" )`, but I'm not sure how to identify a specific piece of data (row/column  pair), so I can put it in a new location in the csv table in comparison to the old excel table.

Comment: just add `df.columns=['one','two','three']` to ensure clarity of csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer based indexing using `iloc`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position

In your case, the row/col value you are looking for can be retrieved by: 
`df.iloc[row_id, col_id]`